# Parse buffered data line by line

Tags: c++, file-io, stl

I want to write a parser for Wavefront OBJ file format, plain text file. 
Example can be seen here: people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/obj/diamond.obj.

Most people use old scanf to parse this format line by line, however I would prefer to load the whole file at once to reduce IO operation count. Is there a way to parse this kind of buffered data line by line?

```
void ObjModelConditioner::Import(Model& asset)
{
    uint8_t* buffer = SyncReadFile(asset.source_file_info());

    delete [] buffer;
}
```

Or would it be preferable to load whole file into a string and try to parse that?

Comment: What format is your input text in? CSV? XML? YAML? etc.

Comment: It's Wavefront OBJ file, plain text file. Example: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/obj/diamond.obj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while It seems I found sufficient (and simple) solution. Since my goal is to create asset conditioning pipeline, the code has to be able to handle large amounts of data efficiently. Data can be read into a `string` at once and once loaded, `stringstream` can be initialized with this string.

```
std::string data;
SyncReadFile(asset.source_file_info(), data);

std::stringstream data_stream(data);
std::string line;
```

Then I simply call `getline()`:

```
while(std::getline(data_stream, line)) 
{        
    std::stringstream line_stream(line);
    std::string type_token;

    line_stream >> type_token;
    if (type_token == "v") {
        // Vertex position
        Vector3f position;
        line_stream >> position.x >> position.y >> position.z;
        // ...
    }
    else if (type_token == "vn") {
        // Vertex normal
    }
    else if (type_token == "vt") {
        // Texture coordinates
    }
    else if (type_token == "f") {
        // Face
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that splits a char array into a vector of strings (assuming each new string starts with '\n' symbol):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::string >split(char * arr)
{
    std::string str = arr;
    std::vector< std::string >result;
    int beg=0, end=0;//begining and end of each line in the array
    while( end = str.find( '\n', beg + 1 ) )
    {
        if(end == -1)
        {
            result.push_back(str.substr(beg));
            break;
        }
        result.push_back(str.substr(beg, end - beg));
        beg = end;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here's the usage:

```
int main()
{
    char * a = "asdasdasdasdasd \n asdasdasd \n asdasd";
    std::vector< std::string >result = split(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the raw data in a `char[]` (or a `unsigned char[]`), and
you know its length, it's pretty trivial to write an input only, no seek
supported `streambuf` which will allow you to create an `std::istream`
and to use `std::getline` on it.  Just call:

```
setg( start, start, start + length );
```

in the constructor.  (Nothing else is needed.)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you're going to parse the text. One way to do this would be simply to read the data into a vector of strings. I'll assume that you've already covered issues such as scaleability / use of memory etc.

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;
ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ios_base::in);
while ( getline( file, line ) )
{
    lines.push_back( line );
}
file.close();
```

This would cache your file in `lines`. Next you need to go through lines

```
for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = lines.begin();
      it != lines.end(); ++it)
{
    const std::string& line = *it;
    if ( line.empty() )
         continue;

    switch ( line[0] )
    {
        case 'g':
            // Some stuff
            break;
        case 'v':
            // Some stuff
            break;
        case 'f':
            // Some stuff
            break;
        default:
            // Default stuff including '#' (probably nothing)
    }
}
```

Naturally, this is very simplistic and depends largely on what you want to do with your file.

The size of the file that you've given as an example is hardly likely to cause IO stress (unless you're using some very lightweight equipment) but if you're reading many files at once I suppose it might be an issue.

I think your concern here is to minimise IO and I'm not sure that this solution will really help that much since you're going to be iterating over a collection twice. **If you need to go back and keep reading the same file over and over again, then it will definitely speed things up to cache the file in memory** but there are just as easy ways to do this such as memory mapping a file and using normal file accessing. If you're really concerned, then try profiling a solution like this against simply processing the file directly as you read from IO.